How to set Quantumult x to skip a specific app
I'm using a software called Quantumult X recently. Through some open source rules, I can skip some application opening screen ads. But I found that when I enabled Quantumult X, I couldn't login in to an iPhone game. I could only login in to the game normally after I turned off Quantumult X. And I also found that when I officially entered the game screen and then turned on Quantumult X, the game could run normally.
I'm a novice. The rules I used were all open source found on github, so I don't know how to set it to skip specific application software. I hope experienced seniors can give me some advice. What operations should be done to log in to the game directly when Quantumult X is turned on, without having to turn off Quantumult X first.
Note: The game is a game on the Chinese IOS platform. The link is: https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/%E9%AD%82%E6%96%97%E7%BD%97-%E5%BD%92%E6%9D%A5-7%E5%91%A8%E5%B9%B4/id983122251
Login in to the game directly when Quantumult X is turned on, without having to turn off Quantumult X first.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
